# Player Object is interacting backwards, how do I fix it?

Tags: unity, c#, rpg

So when my player interacts with an object which the key is right click. For some reason I have no idea for the player model walks backwards. There isn't any error in the console but it is really starting to bug me now. If someone could help me out with that would be greatly appreciated.

**Interact Script**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Interactable : MonoBehaviour {

public float radius = 3f;
public Transform interactionTransform;

bool isFocus = false;
Transform player;

bool hasInteracted = false;

public virtual void Interact ()
{
    // This method is meant to be overwritten
    // Debug.Log("Interacting with" + transform.name);
}

private void Update()
{
    if (isFocus && !hasInteracted)
    {
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(player.position, interactionTransform.position);
        if (distance <= radius)
        {
            Interact();
            hasInteracted = true;
        }
    }
}

public void OnFocused (Transform playerTransform)
{
    isFocus = true;
    player = playerTransform;
    hasInteracted = false;
}

public void OnDefocused ()
{
    isFocus = false;
    player = null;
    hasInteracted = false;
}

private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
{
    if (interactionTransform == null)
        interactionTransform = transform;

    Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
    Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(interactionTransform.position, radius);
}

}
```

**PlayerController Script**

```
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine;

   [RequireComponent(typeof(PlayerMotor))]
   public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

public Interactable focus;

public LayerMask movementMask;

Camera cam;
PlayerMotor motor;

// Use this for initialization
void Start() {
    cam = Camera.main;
    motor = GetComponent<PlayerMotor>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update() {

    if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
        return;

    // If we press left click
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        // We create a ray
        Ray ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;

        // If the ray hits
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100, movementMask))
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                motor.MoveToPoint(hit.point);

                RemoveFocus();
        }
    }
    // If we press right mouse
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
    {
        // We create a ray
        Ray ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100))
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                Interactable interactable = hit.collider.GetComponent<Interactable>();
                if (interactable != null)
                {
                    SetFocus(interactable);
                }
            }
    }
}

void SetFocus(Interactable newFocus)
{
    if (newFocus != focus)
    {
        if (focus != null)
            focus.OnDefocused();

        focus = newFocus;
        motor.FollowTarget(newFocus);
    }

    focus = newFocus;
    newFocus.OnFocused(transform);
    motor.FollowTarget(newFocus);
}

void RemoveFocus()
{
    if (focus != null)
        focus.OnDefocused();

    focus = null;
    motor.StopFollowingTarget();
}
}
```

**PlayerMotor Script**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

[RequireComponent(typeof(NavMeshAgent))]
public class PlayerMotor : MonoBehaviour {

Transform target;       // Target to follow
NavMeshAgent agent;     // Reference to our agent

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
}

public void Update()
{
    if (target != null)
    {
        agent.SetDestination(target.position);
        FaceTarget();
    }
}

public void MoveToPoint (Vector3 point)
{
    agent.SetDestination(point);
}

public void FollowTarget (Interactable newTarget)
{
    agent.stoppingDistance = newTarget.radius * .8f;
    agent.updateRotation = false;

    target = newTarget.interactionTransform;
}

public void StopFollowingTarget()
{
    agent.stoppingDistance = 0f;
    agent.updateRotation = true;

    target = null;
}
private void FaceTarget()
{
    Vector3 direction = (transform.position + transform.position).normalized;
    Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(new Vector3(direction.x, 0f, direction.z));
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, lookRotation, Time.deltaTime * 5f);
}
}
```